# Generating RDF from unstructured text offline

Tags: java, rdf, named-entity-recognition

There are services like Open Calais and Alchemy API that generate RDF from unstructured text. Are there tools that do that offline ? Has anyone tried [WebCAT](http://webcat.sourceforge.net/) or can OpenCyc be useful for such a use-case ?

Answer (score 2):

[Gate](http://gate.ac.uk/) is maybe one of the most popular Java frameworks for text analysis and entity recognition, it also contains components that can generate RDF based on ontologies.

Comment: Thanks for this information. From the docs it appears there is a component called ANNIE that can generate RDF from unstructured text. Will give it a try. Just wondering if this would require some sort of trainer / learner before working on some text ?

Comment: Extractors get plugged into a pipeline. There are many types of different extractors already in GATE that you can reuse, you can also develop your own extractors and plug them in. It your decision if you want to use a Machine Learning algorithm see http://gate.ac.uk/gate/doc/plugins.html#Machine_Learning